# MySQL соответствие поля шаблону

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток.
Почему не получается сделать соответствие поля регулярному выражению- ни одна документация не запрещает это (вроде бы).
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47c95/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id integer ,
value text,
CHECK(value RLIKE '^a+$')
);
INSERT into test set value= 'rt', id=1;
```

Запись успешно вставляется, хотя регулярное выражение должно пропускать только:

```
а
аа
ааа
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHECK можно писать, но он ничего не делает.
Это сделано для обеспечения переносимости баз данных с других серверов.

Это мне подсказал гугл, возможно найденная мной  информация ошибочна.

Comment: Всё верно. "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html